# Deque, Pointers, and Structs in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, deque

Given these data members:

```
private:
    struct DequeNode {                 
        Object item;
        DequeNode *next;
        DequeNode *prev;
    };
    DequeNode *front;
    DequeNode *back;
};
```

I'm confused what the data member front or back would be. Would front just be a pointer that points to DequeNode objects?  So front would not have an item, next, or prev?

This is for an implementation of a deque class.  And it confuses me because in it's getFront method it returns front->next.  I'm under the impression front is just a pointer which does not have a next member.

This is the full header:

```
#ifndef DEQUE_H
#define DEQUE_H
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class Object>
class Deque {
public:
    Deque();                                   // the constructor
    Deque(const Deque &rhs);                  // the copy constructor
    ~Deque();                                  // the destructor

     bool isEmpty() const;                      // checks if a deque is empty.
     int size() const;                          // retrieves # deque nodes
     const Object &getFront() const;            // retrieve the front node
     const Object &getBack() const;             // retrieve the tail node

     void clear();                              // clean up all deque entries.
     void addFront(const Object &obj);         // add a new node to the front
     void addBack(const Object &obj);          // add a new node to the tail
     Object removeFront();                      // remove the front node
     Object removeBack();                       // remove the tail node

     const Deque &operator=(const Deque &rhs); // assignment

private:
    struct DequeNode {                          // a deque node
        Object item;
        DequeNode *next;
        DequeNode *prev;
    };
    DequeNode *front;
    DequeNode *back;
};

#include "deque.cpp.h"
#endif
```

And then this is the cpp:

```
template <class Object>
Deque<Object>::Deque() {                          // the constructor
    front = back = NULL;
}

template <class Object>
Deque<Object>::Deque(const Deque &rhs) {         // the copy constructor
    front = back = NULL;
    *this = rhs;
}

template <class Object>
Deque<Object>::~Deque() {                         // the destructor
    clear();
}

template <class Object>
bool Deque<Object>::isEmpty() const {             // check if a deque is empty
    return front == NULL;
}

template <class Object>
int Deque<Object>::size() const {                 // retrieves # deque nodes
    int i = 0;
    for (DequeNode *ptr = front; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next) // traverse que
    {
        ++i;
    }
    return i;
}

template <class Object>
const Object &Deque<Object>::getFront() const {   // retrieve the front node
    if (isEmpty())
        throw "empty queue";
    return front->item;
}

template <class Object>
const Object &Deque<Object>::getBack() const {    // retrieve the tail node
    if (isEmpty())
        throw "empty queue";
    return back->item;
}

template <class Object>
void Deque<Object>::clear() {          // clean up all entries.
    while (!isEmpty())                 // dequeue till the queue gets empty.
        removeFront();
}

template <class Object>
void Deque<Object>::addFront(const Object &obj) {// add a new node to  front Implement the function body.

}

template <class Object>
void Deque<Object>::addBack(const Object &obj) { // add a new node to tail
                                             // Implement the function body.
}

template <class Object>
Object Deque<Object>::removeFront() {  // remove the front node
                                   // Implement the function body.
}

template <class Object>
Object Deque<Object>::removeBack() {   // remove the tail node
                                   // Implement the function body.
}

template <class Object>
const Deque<Object> &Deque<Object>::operator=(const Deque &rhs) { // assign
    if (this != &rhs) { // avoid self assignment
        clear();
        for (DequeNode *rptr = rhs.front; rptr != NULL; rptr = rptr->next)
            addBack(rptr->item);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

I'm trying to just insert a single object to make sure I'm using the arrow operators correctly, but this keeps giving me a segmentation fault:

```
template <class Object>
void Deque<Object>::addFront(const Object &obj) {// add a new node to  front Implement the function body.
     if (isEmpty())  // If the deque is empty, just throw the item in there.
    {
         front->item = obj;
         front->next = NULL;    
         front->prev = back;

         back->next = front;    
         back->item = obj;
         back->prev = NULL;         
     }
     else
     {
         // Not inserting on an empty list.
     }
}
```

But I keep getting a segmentation fault.  And by adding print statements, it seems it fails at the line "front->item = obj;"
Anyone might know why that's incorrect?

Comment: Use [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) instead.

Comment: Note that `getFront` returns `front->item` (the value of the first item) not `front->next` (the pointer to the second item in the list). This might be what is confusing you.

Comment: @The Dark, you're right.  Sorry about that I was mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Front and Back are respectively the first pointer of your deque and the last one.

The method getFront() as mentioned in the comments provide a way to access the data (item) in it.

But it's not really a [deque](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/), it looks more like a [queue](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/) since there is no iterator defined (maybe you removed them for the clarity of your submission).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct, as "front" is a pointer of type "DequeNode" so "front" is just to point to a "DequeNode" type object. And that's why you can access any member of "DequeNode" type of object which is being pointed by "front" pointer.

On the second problem where you are getting segmentation fault, this is just because you are trying to access "front" which is holding the NULL value when the deque is empty. To get something from "front", it should point to the first object/Node (of type "DequeNode") in the deque when the deque is not empty.

Regarding your third doubt about getFront() method. So the purpose of getFront() method is to get the data part of the front node in the queue and which is "item" in this case.

```
template <class Object>
const Object &Deque<Object>::getFront() const {   // retrieve the front node
    if (isEmpty())
        throw "empty queue";
    return front->item;
}
```